# Accessing a structure which is a member of another structure through pointer in python

Tags: python, pointers, structure, pass-by-reference, ctypes

I have a structure as below

```
class DEVINFO(Structure):
       _fields_ = [("szDeviceName", c_char*MAX_PATH),                                           
                   ("pDevExtension", POINTER(DEVEXTENSION))]
```

In the above, DEVEXTENSION structure is as follows

```
class DEVEXTENSION(Structure):
            _fields_ = [("szProductName",c_char*MAX_PATH),
                        ("szManfName",c_char*MAX_PATH),
                        ("szSerialNumber",c_char*32)]
```

My question is how would i access the members of "DEVEXTENSION" structure.

```
devInfo = DEVINFO()
devInfo.szDeviceName = "USB Flash 302"
print(devInfo.szDeviceName)
```

Comment: Changing your question to a completely different one is a bad practice. You should post a new question. I will revert this one to it's original state.

Comment: @Lattyware Now how would i be able to modification to the above questions or providing something additional to the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the ctypes tutorial](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#pointers):

> Pointer instances have a contents attribute which returns the object
>   to which the pointer points

So, `devInfo.pDevExtensions.contents.szProductName` for example, presuming that `DEVINFO` will produce an *instance* of `DEVEXTENSION` - to me, it isn't obvious it does here (but I'm not familiar with ctypes).

Also note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends `CapWords` for class names, and `CAPS` to be reserved for constants.

Comment: will i be able to assign a value to it like this 'devInfo.pDevExtensions.contents.szProductName = "Transcend"'

Comment: I imagine you will need to make an instance of ``DEVEXTENSION`` with the value you want, then a new pointer to it and then assign that new pointer to ``devInfo.pDevExtensions`` - but that it a guess.

Comment: how will i be able to do so? 'devExt = DEVEXTENSION() devInfo.pDevExtensions = devExt' i get the following error - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/sbritto/Desktop/Sormiou-DI/FinalMacWinlin/Sample.py", line 19, in <module>
    devInfo.pDevExtension = devExt
TypeError: incompatible types, DEVEXTENSION instance instead of LP_DEVEXTENSION instance